# Async method error help me

Tags: c#, asynchronous

**This is Simple Daily Trigger class and I call this function ->("DailyTrigger(int hour, int minute , int second = 0)") from some controller. 
The first time it worked next time( using Task.delay) there is error**

```
public class DailyTrigger
{
    readonly TimeSpan triggerHour;

    public DailyTrigger(int hour, int minute , int second = 0)
    {
        triggerHour = new TimeSpan(hour, minute, second);
        InitiateAsync();
    }

    async void InitiateAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var triggerTime = DateTime.Today + triggerHour - DateTime.Now;
            if (triggerTime < TimeSpan.Zero)
                triggerTime = triggerTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0,2,0));
            await Task.Delay(triggerTime);
            OnTimeTriggered?.Invoke();

        }
    }
```

**Call from in Controller**

```
var trigger = new DailyTrigger(13,01);
                trigger.OnTimeTriggered += () =>
                {
                    var res = AanModel.GetById<Company_Priority>(prio_obj.id);
                    res.version = "5";
                    res.Create();
                };
```

**That error**

> "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you are implementing some kind of scheduled task, then you cannot do it like this.

Comment: If this is in an [tag:asp.net] context, you might want to read [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known issue for asynchronous programming. You'd better read articles like [Quick tip: Avoid ‘async void’](http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/quick-tip-avoid-async-void/) by *jonpreece* to understand how it works.

Error:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

Description:

> Yep, you have a race condition.  The method returned before it
>   finished executing.  Under the hood, the framework didn’t create a
>   Task for the method because the method does not return a Task. 
>   Therefore when calling FirstOrDefaultAsync, the method does not pause
>   execution and the error is encountered.

Solution:

> To resolve the problem, simply change the return type of the method
>   from void to Task.  Don’t worry, you don’t actually have to return
>   anything, and the compiler knows not to generate a build error if
>   there is no return statement.  An easy fix, when you know what the
>   problem is!

UPDATE:

If you still wanna push on calling async methods inside constructors then you better read [Async OOP 2: Constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) by *Stephen Cleary*.

> Asynchronous construction poses an interesting problem. It would be
>   useful to be able to use await in a constructor, but this would mean
>   that the constructor would have to return a Task representing a
>   value that will be constructed in the future, instead of a constructed
>   value. This kind of concept would be very difficult to work into the
>   existing language.
>
> The bottom line is that async constructors are not allowed, so let’s
>   explore some alternatives.

And if you read far enough you'll see..

**What NOT To Do**

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
  private MyData asyncData;
  public MyClass()
  {
    InitializeAsync();
  }

  // BAD CODE!!
  private async void InitializeAsync()
  {
    asyncData = await GetDataAsync();
  }
}
```

Better check it out, it's a very interesting read.

Comment: thank your response. But i can't change void to Task because of i call iInitiateAsync() from public DailyTrigger(int,int,int) . I must await InitiateAsync(); because that call is not awaited.